# QPlainTextEdit - searches the document to the end and again from the beginning

Tags: c++, qt, qplaintextedit, qtextcursor

I want to search in QPlainTextEdit for a string from the current cursor to the end. If nothing is found, I want to continue searching from the start. Only in this stage, if nothing is found, a message will appear.

```cpp
void BasicEdit::findString(QString s, bool reverse, bool casesens, bool words) {

    QTextDocument::FindFlags flag;
    if (reverse) flag |= QTextDocument::FindBackward;
    if (casesens) flag |= QTextDocument::FindCaseSensitively;
    if (words) flag |= QTextDocument::FindWholeWords;
    
    QTextCursor cursor = this->textCursor();
    
    if (!find(s, flag)) {
        //nothing is found | jump to start/end
        cursor.movePosition(reverse?QTextCursor::End:QTextCursor::Start);
        setTextCursor(cursor); //!!!!!!
        if (!find(s, flag)) {
            //no match in whole document
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText(tr("String not found."));
            msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
            msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
            msgBox.exec();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in line `setTextCursor(cursor);`:

- without this line, the search does not continue from the beginning/end.
- with this line, everything is fine except that when the string is not found, the cursor is positioned at the beginning/end of the document, and the current position in the document for the user is lost.

How do I search for a string in a document and not change the current position if none is found?

---

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37610540/17726418), I added value preservation for `verticalScrollBar`.

Even so, there is a short flickering when nothing is found generated by:

```
cursor.movePosition(reverse?QTextCursor::End:QTextCursor::Start);
```

How can we get rid of it? It is an idea to create another invisible QPlainTextEdit element to search in it?

```cpp
void BasicEdit::findString(QString s, bool reverse, bool casesens, bool words)
{

    QTextDocument::FindFlags flag;
    if (reverse) flag |= QTextDocument::FindBackward;
    if (casesens) flag |= QTextDocument::FindCaseSensitively;
    if (words) flag |= QTextDocument::FindWholeWords;
    
    QTextCursor cursor = this->textCursor();
    // here we save the cursor position and the verticalScrollBar value
    QTextCursor cursorSaved = cursor;
    int scroll = verticalScrollBar()->value();
    
    if (!find(s, flag))
    {
        //nothing is found | jump to start/end
        cursor.movePosition(reverse?QTextCursor::End:QTextCursor::Start);
        setTextCursor(cursor);
    
        if (!find(s, flag))
        {
            // word not found : we set the cursor back to its initial position and restore verticalScrollBar value
            setTextCursor(cursorSaved);
            verticalScrollBar()->setValue(scroll);
            QMessageBox msgBox(this);
            msgBox.setText(tr("String not found."));
            msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
            msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
            msgBox.exec();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to keep the cursor position you have **before** starting to search for the word. Then, after the research, *you will set the cursor back to the position you saved*.

```
void BasicEdit::findString(QString s, bool reverse, bool casesens, bool words) 
{
    QTextDocument::FindFlags flag;
    if (reverse) flag |= QTextDocument::FindBackward;
    if (casesens) flag |= QTextDocument::FindCaseSensitively;
    if (words) flag |= QTextDocument::FindWholeWords;

    QTextCursor cursor = this->textCursor();
    // here , you save the cursor position
    QTextCursor cursorSaved = cursor;

    if (!find(s, flag)) 
    {
        //nothing is found | jump to start/end
        cursor.movePosition(reverse?QTextCursor::End:QTextCursor::Start);

        /* following line :
        - the cursor is set at the beginning/end of the document (if search is reverse or not)
        - in the next "find", if the word is found, now you will change the cursor position
        */ 
        setTextCursor(cursor);

        if (!find(s, flag)) 
        {
            //no match in whole document
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText(tr("String not found."));
            msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
            msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
            msgBox.exec();

            // word not found : we set the cursor back to its initial position
            setTextCursor(cursorSaved);
        }
    }
}
```